# Magenot Remove Sort by and Show per page from toolbar

Tags: magento, sorting

How to remove completely Sort By and Show per page from toolbar on product listing with grid view in Magento 1.9.1.0. I have only a few products on my shop so now I don't need sorting and showing functions. What file should I edit and how to change code in this file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely remove the toolbar from the product listing page, you can go to the `list.phtml` file located at below location :

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml and comment the below lines 

1)    <?php //echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
2)    <?php /*<div class="toolbar-bottom">
          <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
        </div> */ ?>
```

My advice would be to copy the list.phtml into your local.